# Angular 4 - User gets logged out between refreshes

Tags: angular, jwt

I'm building an Angular application (using Django as my backend). The problem is that every time the page reloads my user gets automatically signed out. I just started learning Angular, so please forgive me if the answer is too obvious.
Here is my login function in component.ts :

```
  login(username, password) {
    this.auth.login(username, password)
    .subscribe(res => {
      if (res) {
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
      } else {
        this.error = this.error = 'Username or password is incorrect.';
      }
    });
  }
```

And here is my login function in auth.service:

```
    login(username, password) : Observable<boolean> {
      const authUrl = `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api-token-auth/`;
      var credentials = new Credentials(username, password);
      return this.http.post(authUrl, credentials, httpOptions).pipe(
        map(results => {
          if (results['token']) {
            localStorage.setItem('bangular-jwt-token', results['token']);
            this.isLoggedIn = true;

            this.username = username;
            this.user.getUser(this.username).subscribe((users) => {
             this.users = users; 
            });                 
             return true;
          } else {
             return false;
          }
        }),
          catchError(this.eh.handleError<boolean>(`login 
            username=${username}`,false))
          );
     }
```

Comment: what is the JWT expiration seconds?

Comment: @RagavanRajan 30 days

Comment: How do you check in the front if the user is logged in? And if you make any http calls to the backend, did you check that the token was sent, using the network tab of the browser's debugger?

Comment: You should read your jwt token from local storage and save it locally on your auth service init